# Matrix with rank $1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A=(a_{ij})_n$ a symmetric matrix with positive coefficients. We suppose that there is $\alpha>0$ such that, for all permutation $\sigma$ of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, we have
$$a_{1\sigma(1)}a_{2\sigma(2)}\cdots a_{n\sigma(n)}=\alpha.$$
How to prove that the rank of $A$ is $1$? Please any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $\tau$ is another permutation that is the same as $\sigma$ except at two places, say $j$ and $k$, where $\tau(j)=\sigma(k)$ and $\tau(k)=\sigma(j)$.  Subtract the equation you wrote about $\sigma$ from the corresponding equation for $\tau$, and, in the result, cancel all the common factors.  What remains will tell you that a certain $2\times2$ submatrix has determinant $0$.  Repeat for enough $\sigma$'s and $\tau$'s to find that all $2\times2$ submatrices ave determinant $0$.

Comment: Very nice! $\,\,\!$

Comment: Don't you want to divide, instead of subtracting? Nice answer, +1.

Comment: Great, we maybe to reach the perfection  must add that the matrix is not the zero matrix so it's rank not equal $0$.

Comment: @julien No, I want to subtract, so that I get, apart from a lot of common factors, the determinant of a $2\times2$ submatrix.

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. Dividing works, but subtracting is the way.